# MATLAB: 3D array division by 1D vector

Tags: image, matlab, vector, vectorization

I have a 3D array (image) with the dimensions of `256 x 3527 x 8`. I wish to divide all the values by the 3rd dimension by a vector of 1 through 8.

For example, my vector looks like:

```
Esun = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

In each layer of the image of size `256 x 3527` (of 8 layers), I want to divide it by the respective value in `Esun`.

If MATLAB doesn't have such a function, will it be faster to cut my 3D array into 8 pieces and run it through a loop, or turn Esun into a 3D repetitive array and do a matrix division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use `arrayfun` as it is essentially a loop.  Use the mighty [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead combined with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
Esun = 1:8; % Esun = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
B = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, permute(Esun, [1 3 2]));
```

The variable `A` is the 3D matrix that you have that is of size `256 x 3527 x 8`.  The call to `permute` uses `Esun` and converts it into a 3D vector of 1 row and 1 column.  After, `bsxfun` broadcasts the 3D vector so that it becomes a 3D matrix of size `256 x 3527 x 8` where each slice `i` represents the `i`th value in `Esun`.  We then perform the element-wise division.

This basically performs the repetitive array operation that you're speaking of, but the replication is done internally in `bsxfun` and is faster than if you were to create the repetitive array first then perform the division.

Comment: I've read up a bit on using bsxfun and I just have one question: does the type of graphics card I use affect its speed?

Comment: No it doesn't. Graphics memory is only used in MATLAB when using `gpuArray`s and only nVidia cards are supported. Otherwise it should mostly be CPU and RAM that affects performance.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I misread the definition from the mathworks page. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem! Actually could you point me to the documentation you read? I'd like to see for myself.

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/bsxfun.html). I think I found another mathworks page without the term 'gpuArray' in the definition.

Comment: Yes that page refers to `gpuArray`. The link above in my post is the version without `gpuArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayfun` as following:

```
c=arrayfun(@(i) X(:,:,i)*Esun(i),1:8,'UniformOutput',0);
```

Assuming that `X` is your image array. In the above, MATLAB return a 1x8 cell array, then you can use `cat` function to obtain the new array:

```
B = cat(3, c{:}); % cat all cell elements in 3-rd dim
```